# Overloading methods while using Generics with base classes

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following Classes:

```
public abstract class Gear<T> : ScriptableObject, IGear { ... }

public class Armor : Gear<ArmorStatsLevel> { ... }

public class Weapon : Gear<WeaponStatsLevel> { ... }
```

Now I had the following methods to list my instances:

```
public abstract class WidgetListArmor {

    public void ActionSelected(Armor gear) {
        if (...) GameSession.Equip(gear);
    }
}

public abstract class WidgetListWeapon {

    public void ActionSelected(Weapon gear) {
        if (...) GameSession.Equip(gear);
    }
}
```

Because this was kind of redundant, I thought of moving it all to a base clase:

```
public abstract class WidgetListGear<T> : MonoBehaviour {

    public void ActionSelected(T gear) {
        if (...) GameSession.Equip(gear);
    }
}

public class WidgetListArmors  : WidgetListGear<Armor> { ... }

public class WidgetListWeapons : WidgetListGear<Weapon> { ... }
```

And while this seems cleaner, I have a new problem now. Because T is a Generic, `GameSession.Equip` can't overload `gear`.

Did I chose a bad pattern to organize my code? Am I missing something from Generics that allows me to do this operation?

**UPDATE**

Here is the GameSession signatures:

```
public class GameSession {
    public static bool Equip(Armor armor);
    public static bool Equip(Weapon weapon);
}
```

Comment: It all depends on, whether you can re-write your `Equip` method into a single method. There are many patterns that help to push the responsibility for item-specific code onto some other part of the application. However, if you really need to distinguish at that point, the only things I can think of are reflection or a visitor pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Make `Weapon` and `Armor` implement an interface called `IGear`, for example:

```
public interface IGear 
{ }

public class Weapon : IGear
{
    //snip
}

public class Armor : IGear
{
    //snip
}
```

Constrain the generic type to `IGear`:

```
public abstract class WidgetListGear<T> : MonoBehaviour
    where T : IGear
{

    public void ActionSelected(T gear) {
        if (...) GameSession.Equip(gear);
    }
}
```

And make `GameSession.Equip` take `IGear` as the parameter type.

Comment: Weapon and Armor **already** have an IGear interface.

You mean that the signature of `GameSession.Equip` should be `public static bool Equip(IGear gear);`? How would it know then if it receives an Armor or an Weapon? (Because the actions taken then are different..)

Comment: If the actions that it takes are different, then you should have 2 distinct methods instead, don't make a single method do two different things.

Comment: I do have 2 distincts methods. I just want that it overloads to the right one.

Comment: You could have a method on the `IGear` interface called `Equip()` which delegates the responsibility to the item being equipped.

Comment: I totally agree with DavidG here... the item should know best how to equip itself, don't let a 3rd party handle the equipping unless it's a certified fashion designer :)

Comment: But `Gear` is not what decided if something is equipped or not. That is `GameSession`, where I keep track of what is bought, or equipped.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent
Have you checked the dynamic approach I've described? If you want GameSession to manage equipping, it will suit you. As to overall design, I think it's not really relevant to SO.

Comment: @DavidG What would `GameSession.Equip` look like, to diferentiate between armors and weapons?

Comment: You'd have to do some awful thing like `if(gear is Weapon) { /* do weapon stuff */ } else if(gear is Armor) { /* do armor stuff */ }`

Comment: Yeah, that is what I suspected... that is why I am not totally convinced by this answer... :-/

Comment: That's why I didn't suggest doing it that way. Like I said, move the logic somewhere else.

Comment: But where? You say "not in GameSession", but where? it does not belong to "Armor" not "Weapon" to decide what is equipped and what not... and if I move it anywhere else... the problem still remains, no?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is dynamic dispatch. I would suggest you try the following:

```
GameSession.Equip((dynamic)gear);
```

However, I don't think it's the best idea since you've tried to encode your Game rules in type system and right now you're starting a mini-compiler in runtime to perform a dispatch for you.

I'd like to point you to Eric Lippert's [articles](https://ericlippert.com/?s=Wizards%20and%20warriors&submit=Search) on that subject. Looks like you have similar issues with what he's described.

[Part 4](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/07/wizards-and-warriors-part-four/) describes the dynamic approach I've provided as well as its disadvantages. [Part 5](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/11/wizards-and-warriors-part-five/) provides a completely different approach. Overall, I highly recommend reading each part.

Comment: +1 for the linked article... however, the relevant part would probably be part 5 instead of the linked part 4.

Comment: My reasoning was based on the fact that part 4 describes dynamic approach. I think all parts are probably relevant to the question and are definitely useful to read in general.

Comment: Basically at the end of part 4 he concludes that `dynamic` is not really a good approach and promises a better solution ;)

Comment: I've reformulated the answer a little bit so hopefully now we're both OK with it.